# Find all elements (even outside viewport) using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Its my understanding that when the `find_elements`-method is called on a `selenium.webdriver`-instance, it returns a reference of all the elements in the DOM that matches with the provided locator.

When I run the following code I only get <30 elements whereas there are many more on the page in question.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

DRIVER_PATH = '/chromedriver'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)


URL = 'https://labs.actionnetwork.com/markets'
driver.get(URL)
PGA_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//button[@class='btn btn-light' and text()='PGA']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", PGA_button)

logos = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='odds-logo ml-1']")
```

The desired elements:

[image]

How do I do get all the `logos`? When I debug and scroll the page down I get a list of different elements. So, I assume it has something to do with the viewport.

Is there a way to get all the elements on the page (even if they are outside the viewport)?

Comment: Do you want all logos or if two are equal then save only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good strategy is to find all rows visible in the page and then scroll down to the last one so that new rows are loaded in the HTML. In the meanwhile you add the images urls to a `set`. I choose `set` instead of `list` so that duplicate urls are not added, but if you want all the urls then replace the first command with `img = []` and `img.add` with `img.append`.

```
img = set()
number_of_loops = 4

for i in range(number_of_loops):
    print('loop',i+1)
    rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 9).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ag-center-cols-container"]/div[@role="row"]')))
    row_idx = []

    for row in rows:
        img.add(row.find_element(By.XPATH, './/descendant::div[@class="odds-logo ml-1"]/img').get_attribute('src'))
        row_idx.append(int(row.get_attribute('row-index')))
    
    idx_of_max = row_idx.index(max(row_idx))
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', rows[idx_of_max])
    time.sleep(2)

img
```

Output

```
{'https://assets.actionnetwork.com/341144_BetRiver48x48light@2x.png',
 'https://assets.actionnetwork.com/618511_DraftKings48x48lightCopy@2x.png'}
```